# c# linq split list into two parts by entity value

Tags: lambda, group-by

I got tied up over a part of code I need to write.
I got an xml file which I have to import and rework so that I can show up what I need in a datagridview. It is all based on a class Invoice:

```
    public class Invoice
{
    public bool import { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNbr { get; set; }
    public string AltInvoiceNbr { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNbr { get; set; }
    public string AltCustomerNbr { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string FreightAmount { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceAmount { get; set; }
    public string TaxAmount { get; set; }
    public string TaxFreightAmount { get; set; }
    public int PrintSeq { get; set; }
}
```

Within the importfile there are multiple entries for the invoicenbr.
(One per invoice line)
So I did a grouping with following statement.

```
invoices = invoices.GroupBy(i => new
                           {
                               i.InvoiceNbr,
                               i.AltInvoiceNbr,
                               i.CCN,
                               i.CustomerNbr,
                               i.AltCustomerNbr,
                               i.InvoiceDate,
                               i.PrintSeq
                           }).Select(i => new Invoice()
                           {
                               InvoiceNbr = i.Key.InvoiceNbr,

                               AltInvoiceNbr = i.Key.AltInvoiceNbr,
                               CCN = i.Key.CCN,
                               CustomerNbr = i.Key.CustomerNbr,
                               AltCustomerNbr = i.Key.AltCustomerNbr,
                               InvoiceDate = i.Key.InvoiceDate,
                               Amount = i.Sum(x =>  decimal.Parse(x.Amount)).ToString("F"),
                               FreightAmount = i.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.FreightAmount)).ToString("F"),
                               InsuranceAmount = i.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.InsuranceAmount)).ToString("F"),
                               TaxAmount = i.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.TaxAmount)).ToString("F"),
                               TaxFreightAmount = i.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.TaxFreightAmount)).ToString("F"),
                               PrintSeq = i.Key.PrintSeq
                           }).ToList();
```

So the output looks nice in a datagridview. Now there are some rows e.g. for credits (or partial shipments) where the invoice number appears two or more times. In this case the PrintSeq is >1.

I need to filter out that data.

e.g. for a credit there are two entries.
One with InvoiceNbr 20160420-1 with an amount of 50$ and another
with the same InvoiceNbr with an amount of -50$.

The printSeq for +50$ invoice is 1.
The printSeq for -50$ invoice is 2.

I tried to filter with

```
.Where(x=>x.PrintSeq = 1)
```

but in this case one entry stays in the output.

If I use

```
.Where(x=>x.PrintSeq != 1)
```

I get a list which shows the InvoiceNbrs which I don't want to show in the output.

So I am searching now a possibility to use that list to filter out all invoiceNbrs on the original output with Lambda expressions.

(Select * from invoices 
where originallist.invoicenbr IS NOT filterlist.invoicenbr)

I **dont** want to use external libraries etc.
(distinctby)
I tried to use distinct on the original list by using a nested groupby first but that seems not the right way.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
        SetInvoices(); //fills List<Invoice> invoices

        SetManualInvoices(); 
        // fills List<Invoice> manualinvoices with .Where(x=> x.printSeq >1)

        invoices = invoices.Where(i=> !manualinvoices.Any(m=>m.InvoiceNbr == i.InvoiceNbr))
        .ToList();
        //select every invoice from invoices where invoicenbr is not in manualinvoices.
        return invoices;
```

Thanks :D